# Escaping a single quote when using JdbcTemplate For Dynamic WHERE

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I am using JdbcTemplate to query the database however i am building a dynamic WHERE clause and i want to escape quotes. Under is an example of how my string looks :

There are times that they would not be any where clause since the user may want to return all records. So using prepared statement may not be feasible here.

**JdbcTemplate**

```
String sql = "select crime.*, "+
                     "criminalSocialSecurityNumber,criminal.fName as criminalFName,criminal.lName as criminalLName,"+
                     "criminal.photo as criminalPhoto,criminal.dob as criminalDob,victimSocialSecurityNumber,"+
                     "victim.fName as victimFName,victim.lName as victimLName,victim.photo as victimPhoto, victim.dob as victimDob "+ 
                     "from tblcrimes crime "+
                     "left join tblcriminalcrime on crime.crimeRecNo = tblcriminalcrime.crimeRecNo "+
                     "left join tblvictimcrime on crime.crimeRecNo = tblvictimcrime.crimeRecNo "+
                     "inner join tblcitizens criminal on criminal.socialSecurityNumber = tblcriminalcrime.criminalSocialSecurityNumber "+
                     "inner join tblcitizens victim on victim.socialSecurityNumber = tblvictimcrime.victimSocialSecurityNumber " + where_clause;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using prepared statement is perfectly possible, and is what you should do.

Build your query dynamically, using placeholders (`?`) for every argument, and each time you add a placeholder, also add the argument value to a list of arguments. In the end, you have a parameterized SQL query, and a list of argument values to bind to the prepared statement.

Something like

```
List<Object> args = new ArrayList<Object>();
StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();
if (criteria.getFoo() != null) {
    whereClause.append(" and foo = ?");
    args.add(criteria.getFoo());
}
if (criteria.getBar() != null) {
    whereClause.append(" and bar = ?");
    args.add(criteria.getBar());
}
// ...

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query + whereClause);
int i = 1;
for (Object arg : args) {
    stmt.setObject(i, arg);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I am getting the floowing error : HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement

Comment: I has an error in my answer, sorry. I fixed it. You must not use com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement. Only java.sql.PreparedStatement. And connection.prepareStatement() must be used to get a PreparedStatement instance.

Comment: I have another concern with this how do i include there 'WHERE' in this query do i need to do append it to the begining of the list or will prepared statements take care of this for me?

Comment: I did a query and it's telling me syntax error and its happening after the from tablename there is an 'and'

Comment: You must of course append this so that the result is a valid SQL query. A good strategy would be to start it with `select ... where 1 = 1`, and then appending the dynamically created part.